# Unable to access Web Adapter 10.2.2 through JBoss EAP 6.1.0

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-10.2

I am working on ArcGIS server 10.2.2 for Java but facing some problem related to Web Adapter.

I have successfully configured Web Adapter with JBoss web server and able to access it from its URL (http://x.x.x.x:8080/arcgis/webadapter) but the problem is that after changing the  port of JBoss server to 80, Web Adapter is not accessible from URL. When I reconfigured Web Adapter with some other name for say geoservice (http://x.x.x.x/geoservice/webadapter) it's working fine.

Can't we use same Web Adapter with JBoss server running on different ports?